# How to Draw Rectangle on Bitmap image, keeping image in the centre?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to draw a rectangle over the bitmap image using onTouchEvent method so onTouch there should be a rectangle around the image. The code below creates the rectangle but it doesn't have any relation to the image unfortunately, it gets drawn on top left hand corner regardless of where the image is. How can I achieve this ?

```
class DrawingView extends View{

    float x=0f,y=0f;
    float dX,dY;

    public DrawingView(Context context){
        super(context);
        viewCapture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.main);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = this.getX () - (int)event.getX();
                dY = this.getY () - (int)event.getY();
                invalidate();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = (int)event.getX();
                y = (int)event.getY();
                y += dY;
                x += dX;
                this.setY(y);
                this.setX(x);
                invalidate();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x =(int)event.getX();
                y =(int)event.getY();
                y += dY;
                x += dX;
                this.setY(y);
                this.setX(x);
                invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(viewCapture, x, y, paint);

        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+viewCapture.getWidth() / 2, y+viewCapture.getHeight()/ 2, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> it gets drawn on top left hand corner regardless of where the image is

Because you are drawing with half size of your Bitmap.

```
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+viewCapture.getWidth() / 2, y+viewCapture.getHeight()/ 2, paint);
}
```

Here you are using `viewCapture.getWidth() / 2` and `viewCapture.getHeight()/ 2`

You have to draw Rectangle with full of the `Bitmap` with and height.

```
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+viewCapture.getWidth(), y+viewCapture.getHeight(), paint);
```

One more thing don't initialize `Paint` object inside `onDraw` method as this method is called frequently. It will take lot of memory by initializing many `Paint` object.

use a method initialize `Paint` in Constructor.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) official doc about CustomView

**Edit:**

Use this code for moving with TouchEvent and drawing border over Bitmap.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.yousuf.shawon.customviews.R;

import static android.content.Context.WINDOW_SERVICE;

public class DrawingView extends View {

    float dX,dY;
    Bitmap bitMap;
    Paint paint;

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    float preX, preY;

    private static final String TAG = "DrawingView";

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context){


        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        Log.i(TAG, "init: Screen Width: " + screenWidth + " Screen Height: " + screenHeight);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.playbtn);
    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                preX = event.getRawX();
                preY = event.getRawY();

                try {
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
                    int bottom = parent.getBottom();
                    screenHeight = bottom;
                }catch (Exception e){

                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                dX = event.getRawX() - preX ;
                dY = event.getRawY() - preY;

                preX = event.getRawX();
                preY = event.getRawY();

                float newX = getX() + dX;
                float newY = getY() + dY;

                if(( newX  >= 0 && newX < screenWidth-getWidth() ) && ( newY >= 0 && newY < screenHeight - getHeight() )  ){
                    setX(getX() + dX);
                    setY(getY() + dY);
                }

                invalidate();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent: UP");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int contentWidth = bitMap.getWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        int contentHeight = bitMap.getHeight() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        int measuredWidth = resolveSize(contentWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredHeight = resolveSize(contentHeight, heightMeasureSpec);


        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }




    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

            float startX = getPaddingLeft() ;
            float startY = getPaddingTop() ;

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, startX  , startY , paint);
            canvas.drawRect(startX, startY, startX + bitMap.getWidth(), startY + bitMap.getHeight(), paint);


    }
}
```

In `xml`:

```
    <com.yousuf.shawon.customviews.views.DrawingView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    />
```

**Edit 2:**
make your custom width and height with fixed value so that you can drag and drop easily. If your Bitmap is too big than resize it and draw it with small Rect

Use this in `xml`

```
    <com.yousuf.shawon.customviews.views.DrawingView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this gives me Rectangle around whole of the canvas  I want the rectangle to be  just Around the image.

Comment: whats your `DrawingView` size

Comment: How do I find that out ?

Comment: Thank you I've tried it, unfortunately there is no drag and it has red Rectangle over whole canvas.

Comment: Actually this will take width and height as like as Bitmap. Try using small width and height Bitmap.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by 'small width and height Bitmap'

Comment: I have tried all of the above without any success, some more ideas please.